# Iterating over dict and values don't always print

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm having a really strange issue here that I can't figure out. The first time the following code executes, it works as you would expect, cities and countries are printed correctly. Every time after that, nothing is printed.

```
for tweet in tweets:
    city = tweet['city']
    country = tweet['country']
    print("{}, {}".format(city, country))
```

If I just print the entire dict, I can see that city and country ARE in there and they have values. I do have some worker threads in the background that update the city and country, but I can't figure out why that would affect it, if it is.

Comment: `tweets` is probably a generator that can only be used once.

Comment: Can we see some more code for context?

Comment: Ahhh, thanks @PaulH, went back and fixed my __next__ to reset at the end and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, for anyone that happens to have a similar issue, was that in my __next__ function in my Tweet class I wasn't resetting the iterator. So after iterating over the object once, the position was at the end of the list and was never being put back at the beginning.